# Unexpected font in CListCtrl?

Tags: visual-c++, clistctrl

I have a CListCtrl object and I use:

```
AddData(m_listControl, 0, 0, "  Abc ");
```

This works fine in older version of Visual Studio (2008).
However in Visual Studio 2013 I am using UNICODE character set, and the above displays a strange font in the List Control Box.

Can someone please tell me how to insert (AddData or another way) so that the CListCtrl displays english character set?

Answer (score 0):

Use TEXT( "  Abc  " ). TEXT() macro makes strings Unicode or ASCII depending on compiler settings.

Comment: Hi i486 That is the problem. I cannot add _T("") as the compiler complains: "Cannot convert argument 4 from 'const wchar_t[29]' to 'const char*'

Comment: It seems CListCtrl is ANSI/ASCII only, not Unicode and for that reason you get the error. Typically, I don't like MFC and prefer pure Win32 API. You can switch the project to MultiByte (non-Unicode), or set the font for CListCtrl. The 3rd way is to get the HWND for CListCtrl and use SendMesssage( hwndCtl, LVM_* ... to work with Unicode strings.

Comment: BTW, what is this AddData method? I cannot find it in MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Well, why did you use this title:

> "Unexpected font in CListCtrl?"

your problem has nothing to do with a font.

It also has nothing to do with list view control. It is AddData function that is giving you a hard time.

I am sure that in parameter list, the fourth argument is defined as const char*. You will have to change function’s signature. 
Try LPCTSTR as type.
Than, follow i486's answer.